# Is there any component available in Camel to run standalone route?

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-sql, camel-jdbc

I want a child route to run from a Timer route but the following code is not running properly:

Child route:

```java
from("direct:processOrder").id("dd")
//  .setBody(constant("select * from customer"))
//  .to("jdbc:testdb")
    .to("sql:select * from EMPLOYEE?dataSource=masterdata")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "DB")
    .to("log:?level=INFO&showBody=true").end();
```

Main route:

```java
from("timer://foo?period=30000")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Triggered Company")
    .process(new Processor() {
      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.getContext().startRoute("dd");
      }
    })
    .end();
```

Output:

```
20/03/05 13:28:07 INFO impl.DefaultCamelContext: StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
20/03/05 13:28:08 INFO impl.DefaultCamelContext: Route: dd started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://processOrder]
20/03/05 13:28:08 INFO impl.DefaultCamelContext: Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[timer://foo?period=30000]
20/03/05 13:28:08 INFO impl.DefaultCamelContext: Total 2 routes, of which 2 is started.
20/03/05 13:28:08 INFO impl.DefaultCamelContext: Apache Camel 2.15.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.400 seconds
20/03/05 13:28:09 INFO route1: Triggered Company
20/03/05 13:28:09 INFO impl.DefaultCamelContext: Route: dd started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://processOrder]
```

What component to be used in `from` of the child route so that it just runs when we `.startRoute` from the main route program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your log, both routes started correctly, so you don't need to execute `.startRoute` explicitly.

To pass a signal to another route, call `.to("direct:processOrder")` in your parent route instead of running the processor you have now:

```java
from("timer://foo?period=30000")
  .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Triggered Company")
  .to("direct:processOrder")
  .end()
```

Answer (score 1):

See [direct component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/direct-component.html). Using "to" instead of ".process":

```
.to("direct:processOrder");
```